# ctags not getting functions whose return value types are above the function names

Tags: c, ctags

I am working with some code which has the following style:

```
int
add5 (int x) {
    return x+5;
}
```

In other words, the return value type of the function is written right above the function's name. Because of that, `ctags` is not recognizing these functions and causing me a terrible headache. Does someone know how to get `ctags` to handle this case?

**EDIT**: `ctags` *can* recognize the function names on .c files but what I need is `ctags` to recognize the function names on `.h` files. On the .h files I have things such as:

```
int
add5 (int);
```

and there `ctags` does not recognize `add5`.

Comment: Above? It's in `return`.

Comment: It works for me with **Exuberant Ctags 5.8** running it like `ctags *`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to tell `ctags` to search for prototypes of functions. It is done with `--<LANG>-kinds` option.

So, run following command:

```
ctags --c-kinds=+p *
```

And it will add the declaration to the `tags` file, as you can see in the output of my test:

```
!_TAG_FILE_FORMAT       2       /extended format; --format=1 will not append ;" to lines/
!_TAG_FILE_SORTED       1       /0=unsorted, 1=sorted, 2=foldcase/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_AUTHOR    Darren Hiebert  /dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_NAME      Exuberant Ctags //
!_TAG_PROGRAM_URL       http://ctags.sourceforge.net    /official site/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_VERSION   5.8     //
add5    add.h   /^add5 (int);$/;"       p
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like `ctags` is recognizing the function but not finding its declaration.

In fact, if you create this function in a header file:

```
int
plus(int a,int b) {
    return a+b;
}
```

`ctags` can find it.